# Bayesian belief updating on single values using the sum of log odds

Tags: probability, bayesian, belief-propagation

Suppose I want to perform Bayesian belief updating using only two values (the value estimate for option 1 (x) and the value estimate for option 2 (y)). I don't have any knowledge about the underlying distribution. So at time step 1 I get 2 values [x,y], and at time step 2 I get another two values [x,y]. I would like to update my belief using the sum of log odds (maybe assuming an underlying Gaussian distribution). However, I only get two values so I don't have a measure of variance or a likelihood function. How would I implement this? I would like a step by step explanation of the implementation so that I can code it.

Comment: Can you offer a more detailed explanation?  What are the x and y you observe?

Comment: Here they represent values for option A and option B. They can take on any positive value.